# Tensorflow Dataset API doubles graph protobuff filesize

Tags: python, tensorflow, skflow

**Summary**: Using the new tf.contrib.data.Dataset doubles the size of my graph protobuff file and I'm unable to visualize the graph in Tensorboard.

**The details:**

I'm trying out the new TensorFlow [`tf.contrib.data.Dataset`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/programmers_guide/datasets.md) functionality together with the [`tf.contrib.learn.Experiment`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) framework. My input data is defined as [input functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn) which return tensors of features and labels.

If I create my input function with the [`tf.train.slice_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/slice_input_producer) function like in the following codeblock (full code [here](https://gist.github.com/peterroelants/bbb67fb4e7dad69c79102fec90737a53#file-mnist_old_data-py)), then my resulting `graph.pbtxt` file is 620M and the `.meta` files are around 165M in size.

```
def train_inputs():
    with tf.name_scope('Training_data'):
        x = tf.constant(mnist.train.images.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]))
        y = tf.constant(mnist.train.labels)
        sliced_input = tf.train.slice_input_producer(
            tensor_list=[x, y], shuffle=True)
        return tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            sliced_input, batch_size=batch_size,
            capacity=10000, min_after_dequeue=batch_size*10)
```

Now if I create my input function with the new [`tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices) like in the following codeblock (full code [here](https://gist.github.com/peterroelants/bbb67fb4e7dad69c79102fec90737a53#file-mnist_new_dataset-py)), then my resulting `graph.pbtxt` file doubles in size to 1.3G and the `.meta` files double in size to 330M.

```
def train_inputs():
    with tf.name_scope('Training_data'):
        images = mnist.train.images.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
        labels = mnist.train.labels
        dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
            (images, labels))
        dataset = dataset.repeat(None)  # Infinite
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
        dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        next_example, next_label = iterator.get_next()
        return next_example, next_label
```

Now because the `graph.pbtxt` file is so big TensorBoard takes ages to parse this file, and I'm unable to debug my model graph visually.
I found in the [Dataset documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/programmers_guide/datasets.md) that this increase in size comes from: *"the contents of the array will be copied multiple times"* and the [solution](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/programmers_guide/datasets.md#consuming-numpy-arrays) would be to use placeholders. However, in this case, I would need to feed in the numpy arrays into the placeholders with an active session to initialize the iterator:

```
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: features, labels_placeholder: labels})
```

This seems, however, to be out of my control when using the `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` framework.

How can I initialize the iterator's initialiser with the Experiment framework? Or find a workaround to using the Dataset API without increasing my graph size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem using [`tf.train.SessionRunHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SessionRunHook). I create a `SessionRunHook` object that initialises the iterator after the session is created:

```
class IteratorInitializerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IteratorInitializerHook, self).__init__()
        self.iterator_initiliser_func = None

    def after_create_session(self, session, coord):
        self.iterator_initiliser_func(session)
```

The initializer function is set when creating the Dataset Iterator:

```
iterator_initiliser_hook.iterator_initiliser_func = \
    lambda sess: sess.run(
        iterator.initializer,
        feed_dict={images_placeholder: images,
                   labels_placeholder: labels})
```

And I pass in the hook objects to `train_monitors` and `eval_hooks` parameters of `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment`.

The resulting `graph.pbtxt` file is now only 500K while the `.meta` files are only 244K.

[**Full example here.**](https://gist.github.com/peterroelants/6a7b3cc802f7f855744e3a74a1fab354#file-mnist_new_dataset_hook-py)

Comment: Nice. also solves my problem. but seems like a workaround?
My post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207211/tensorflow-dataset-api-causes-graph-size-to-explode