# How to pass parameters to the thread, operating on tensorflow graph?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I would like to run a thread, which will populate a queue on the computation graph from normal python operations. The thread will use `sess` object, some of tensors and some data.

How to pass data to the thread?

Here is seen some sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34596212/258483

`load_and_enqueue` function should be ran in a separate thread. It is started with

```
t = threading.Thread(target=load_and_enqueue)
t.start()
```

but how `sess` and `enqueue_op` reach inside of a thread? These declared as function parameters, so it is not a closure. So, is this author's error or Python allows this way of sending parameters?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function `load_and_enqueue(foo, bar, baz)` and you want to run it in a thread with particular values for the arguments, you can start it with those arguments as follows:

```
def load_and_enqueue(foo, bar, baz):
  # ...

foo_arg = ...
bar_arg = ...
baz_arg = ...

t = threading.Thread(target=load_and_enqueue, args=(foo_arg, bar_arg, baz_arg))
t.start()
```

**N.B.** The [original SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34596212/3574081) has been modified because it was intended to simply capture the variables from the enclosing scope.

Comment: Is it possible to capture values? To capture values, shouldn't I remove variables from argument list?

Comment: Yes, the thread will capture values defined before the function, so (approximately speaking) if there were variables `foo`, `bar` and `baz` defined before the function, you would not need (i) define them as formal arguments to the function, and (ii) pass them as `args` in the thread constructor.